# Delete Azure Log Analytics solution after Workspace was deleted

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I had an Azure Log Analytics Worspace with two Solutions and I deleted the Workspace without deleting the Solutions. Now when I try to delete the Solutions I'm getting an `Unknown error` from the portal.

I've tried deleting the resource using PowerShell but it still doesn't work and I dont't get a specific error also.

Answer (score 1):

Well... It seems that after some time after the Workspace is deleted the Solutions are deleted automatically, but it takes some time and is somewhat confusing. So keeping this question and answer here to save future time of others experiencing the same problem ;-)